# How to set Processing to run in 32-bit on OS X?

Tags: processing

I have os x mavericks with Processing 2. I want to make all the sketches run in 32 bit because I am using a library that needs this (OpenCV). I can't find the option in the Preferences. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

in Finder select the "Processing 2" application and get info on it (File -> Get Info). there should be a checkbox in the info panel for running in 32bit mode. Questions like this are best asked on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I couldn't find this option on my Mavericks MAC. Seems like this option doesn't exist anymore- or the most recent version of processing can't run it.